# Why are 2 keyword arguments being interpreted as 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why does the following work to correct disable a radio button in a form:

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'set_creation_radio', 'set_editor', false, disabled: true %>
```

But this does not (note addition of keyword argument `checked`):

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'set_creation_radio', 'set_editor', checked: false, disabled: true %>
```

When using a breakpoint at this location, `checked` produces the following output in the first (i.e. working) instance:

```
0> checked
=> true
```

whereas the second seems to interpret both keywords as a single argument:

```
0> checked
=> {:checked=>true, :disabled=>true}
```

This is the source code for `radio_button_tag` and I do not understand why `checked` would be interpreted as a hash in my example:

```
      def radio_button_tag(name, value, checked = false, options = {})
        html_options = { "type" => "radio", "name" => name, "id" => "#{sanitize_to_id(name)}_#{sanitize_to_id(value)}", "value" => value }.update(options.stringify_keys)
        html_options["checked"] = "checked" if checked
        tag :input, html_options
      end
```

Comment: _"note addition of keyword argument checked"_ – you can't just "invent" arguments. Take a look at the method definition and you'll see that it takes 4 _positional_ arguments. None of them is a _keyword_ argument. Ruby therefore concludes that your `checked: false` is part of the hash.

Comment: Sorry if that phrasing was confusing, I was referring to "addition" in that I included the keyword in the second example but NOT the first. The method definition takes 2 positional (`name`, `value`) and 2 keyword (`checked`, `options`) arguments, does it not?

Comment: No, `checked = false` and `options = {}` are [positional arguments with default values](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Default+Values). [Keyword arguments](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments) inside the method definition would be `checked: false` or `options: {}` (note the colon after the argument name).

Comment: Wow ok. Did not know that difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example the false value is passed explicitly as the checked argument and the disabled variable is interpreted as the options parameter. This means that disabled is treated as a separate argument and gets merged with the default options hash (which is empty in this case).

But in 2nd example the checked: false and disabled: true are passed as a single hash argument to the options parameter. In this case, options includes both the checked and disabled keys.

In the first example, the checked value is explicitly set to false, so it remains false and is not overridden. But in the second example, checked is included as part of the options hash, so it takes the value false from there. To fix the second example:

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'set_creation_radio', 'set_editor', false, disabled: true %>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no magic in calling a method in Ruby that says "oh, that's a hash, so I'll move that to the fourth argument". So in your second example you have three arguments:

- `'set_creation_radio'`
- `'set_editor'`
- `{ checked: false, disabled: true }`

So those are assigned to the first three parameters in the `radio_button_tag` method call, ie.

- `name = 'set_creation_radio'`
- `value = 'set_editor'`
- `checked = { checked: false, disabled: true }`

Comment: But in `radio_button_tag` there ARE 4 arguments, aren't there? `name`, `value`, `checked`, `options`. So my assumption would be that `name = set_creation_radio`, `value = set_editor`, `checked = false`, `options = { disabled: true }`. Why is `disabled: true` not being interpreted as the `options` ?

Comment: You're getting confused between a position argument with a default value (ie. `checked = false`) and a keyword argument (which would be `checked: false`).